# Redirect curl output to open the HTML response in chrome?

Tags: curl, terminal

I made a request via curl and the output is (a huge) HTML document, which is not possible to usefully interpret in the terminal.

How can it be redirected to display in chrome?

Here is the curl

```
curl -X PUT -d listing_id_created=True localhost:3000/products/27
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone knows better ways but I found this

```
curl -X PUT -d listing_id_created=True localhost:3000/products/27 > apiresponse.html && open apiresponse.html
```

Note that it will only work if chrome is the default browser (otherwise it will open in whatever the default browser is)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the HTML on your machine and then open it using Chrome or any other browser.

`curl -X PUT -d listing_id_created=True localhost:3000/products/27 --output some.file`

Surely not the most elegant way, but it was the first thing that came to my mind.

Regards.